# SQL - group for every 2 records

Tags: sql, oracle

Original Table:

```
id    rank
A      1  
B      1  
D      2  
E      2  
G      3  
H      3  
I      4  
J      5  
K      6  
L      6  
M      7
```

Would like to add one more group column - the value will be + 1 every 2 record:

```
id    rank  group 
A      1      1
B      1      1
D      2      1
E      2      1
G      3      2
H      3      2
I      4      2
J      5      3
K      6      3
L      6      3
M      7      4
```

What I can think is only able to hardcode a "case when" condition for ranking. Since the table could be large, is there another function that can group the record dynamically?

Case when rank >0 and rank <=2 then 1

When rank >2 and rank <=4 then 2

When rank >4 and rank <=6 then 3 end group

....

Comment: What is your database ?

Comment: Oracle database

Comment: Your case statement in your question does not match your expected results ? >> D      2      1
E      2      1 (When rank >1 and rank <=2 then 2)

Comment: Why ids D and E have group = 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using <kbd>[`ceil()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions017.htm)</kbd> function would be a direct option after dividing `rate` column by `2` :

```
SELECT id, rank, ceil( rank / 2 ) as "group"
  FROM tab;
```

*Btw, I replaced `group` with `"group"` since it is a reserved keyword*

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable using `dense_rank()`

```
select dense_rank() over (partition by rank % 2  order by id) as grouping, rank 
from tableA 
order by rank
```